# Alter track labels in AVPlayerViewController for HLS

Tags: xamarin.ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I play HLS stream with AVPlayer and AVPLayerViewController on Xamarin.iOS. The problem is that I can't change names of the tracks (audio and subtitles) that user can select in playback options.
[Labels I want to change are marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdt3C.png) Ex I want to have there native language names.

Lets say I can't change metadata in the stream and I have to change track labels in the player.
This is how I parse available tracks and select English for subs and audio.

```cs
AVAsset asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(source);
AVPlayerItem playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(asset);

foreach (string characteristic in this.playerItem.Asset.AvailableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions)
{
    AVMediaSelectionGroup group = this.playerItem.Asset.MediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic(characteristic);
    AVMediaSelectionOption option = group.Options.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Playable && o.ExtendedLanguageTag == "eng");

    if (option is null)
        continue;

    this.playerItem.SelectMediaOption(option, group);
}
```

I tried to change AVMediaSelectionGroup and AVMediaSelectionOption, but instances have pretty much read only properties.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: fx298 It's difficult to understand, could you please give more details of what you are trying to do and what you are trying to display?

Comment: @Saamer Post updated, I hope linked screen explains the issue. I'm able to select any option available, but I can't influence how option is displayed to the user.

Comment: I don't think you can change the display labels.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your time guys, take care.